# My drivers side window no longer closes with one press of the button 1

Tags: electrical, subaru, forester

I share a [similar plight with the guy before](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/3956/37) only difference is it's with an 04 Forester STi. I held the passenger front window switch up for a little too long next thing I know my driver side window goes all the way to the top and the safety mechanism kicks in as if something is in its way which would make the window automatically return to half way open.

I then proceeded to hold down the window switch of both the passenger and driver side for maybe 5 seconds, then 10 then 15 and ultimately 25 second intervals, after which the driver side resumed normal operations.

As soon as I'd turn off the car however the unwanted behavior would return :(. I have all but given up and would love to hear from a Subaru manual as I reside in the Caribbean and have no Subaru dealer to turn to (my vehicle was imported from Japan.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My drivers side window no longer closes with one press of the button](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3956/my-drivers-side-window-no-longer-closes-with-one-press-of-the-button)

Answer (score 4):

My local Subaru dealer tried the same techniques you tried, and also tried to replace with a normal Forester window unit. Unfortunately here in the UK the STi is an import from Japan, so their conclusion was that they would need to replace the entire module - so hopefully I have one coming from Japan and will get it next month.

Apparently there is not a lot that is serviceable in the window module - expectation is that if it won't reset, then it's a replace.

Until then, I can only get the window to the top in small (1 inch) increments.